# `pass` is missing `wl-copy` after upgrade to 21.10

Tags: password, do-release-upgrade, clipboard

After upgrading from Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10 the password manager `pass` will try to use `wl-copy` and `wl-paste` instead of `xclip` if provided the `-c` option.

```
$ pass -c my/password
/usr/bin/pass: line 180: wl-copy: command not found
Error: Could not copy data to the clipboard
```

Comment: Still present in ubuntu 22.04 although [fixed in master](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/commit/?id=85bb62f47ac2f518bfdb36c5dfedf5938219a9b7) we need to wait for pass v1.7.5, or clone from master ourselves.

Answer (score 16):

`wl-copy` is part of the `wl-clipboard` package.

I found that the [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=wl-copy&mode=exactfilename&suite=impish&arch=any) `wl-clipboard` was still missing on my machine after I moved from Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10.

I installed it with:

```
sudo apt install wl-clipboard
```

And then `pass -c ...` worked fine.

Comment: this seems to work also with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)